# Corretto JDK 21 Build 35 crash: [libjvm.so+0x840016] G1ParCopyClosure<(G1Barrier)

Tags: java, corretto, java-21

### Questions

- Have you seen or encountered the error listed below?
- Thoughts or suggestions as to how one might diagnose this?
- If this is a JDK bug, suggestions as to where this might best be reported?

### Environment

- Corretto JDK 21 Build 35 (Also tried with Zulu JDK 21 Build 35)
- GitHub Actions CI - Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Gradle 8.4 RC1

### Crash

Java Runtime crashes with the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f58e7c40016, pid=3580, tid=3599
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-21.0.0.35.1 (21.0+35) (build 21+35-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-21.0.0.35.1 (21+35-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x840016]  G1ParCopyClosure<(G1Barrier)0, false>::do_oop(oopDesc**)+0x56
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /home/runner/work/cas/cas/support/cas-server-support-ldap-core/core.3580)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/runner/work/cas/cas/support/cas-server-support-ldap-core/hs_err_pid3580.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/corretto/corretto-21/issues/
#
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0044440016, pid=3611, tid=3615
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-21.0.0.35.1 (21.0+35) (build 21+35-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-21.0.0.35.1 (21+35-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x840016]  G1ParCopyClosure<(G1Barrier)0, false>::do_oop(oopDesc**)+0x56
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /home/runner/work/cas/cas/support/cas-server-support-ldap/core.3611)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/runner/work/cas/cas/support/cas-server-support-ldap/hs_err_pid3611.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/corretto/corretto-21/issues/
```

Comment: From the error _"If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit: https://github.com/corretto/corretto-21/issues/"_

Comment: Have you tried the openjdk? https://jdk.java.net/21/ Can you provide the reproducer?

Comment: Also from the error: _An error report file with more information is saved as: /[...]/hs_err_pid3580.log_. That file is important if you want to understand what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with netty native libraries that were not compatible with JDK 21. Netty 4.1.99.Final fixes this.

> Netty 4.1.99.Final released: We are happy to announce the release of netty 4.1.99.Final. This release fixes a bug which could lead to SIGSERV while running on JDK21+. As JDK21 was recently released and is considered an LTS release we did decided to do this emergency release. Because of the nature of this bug (crashing the JVM) you should upgrade ASAP.

https://netty.io/news/2023/09/21/4-1-99-Final.html